# Regex for object dimensions

Tags: php, regex

http://regexr.com/3eg8c

Text:

```
(18.8 x 25.7 x 1.8 cm)
10.787 x 8.031 x 1.339"
2.75 x 6.5 x 6.5 in
31 x 21.89 x 1.89 cm 
(18.8 x 25.7 x 1.8 cm)
10.787 x 8.031 x 1.339"
2.75  x  6.5  x  6.5 in
31x21.89x1.89 mm
```

Expression:

```
/(\d*\.?\d+) x (\d*\.?\d+)(?: x (\d*\.?\d+))\s*(cms?|in|inch|inches|mms?)\b/ig
```

Currently matches some of the values from my test case, but i'd like it to:

- Make sure exactly 3 values are found (1x2x3) no more, no less.
- Ignore spaces between the numbers as well as the number and unit.
- Include unit in the capture group.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/YqsvoJ/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change will give you what you are looking for:

```
/^(?:[\(])?(\d*\.?\d+)\s*x\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*x\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*((?:cms?|in|inch|inches|mms?)\b|(?:[\"]))/igm
```

You can check here:
http://regexr.com/3eg8i

This is the breakdown:

1. start at the beginning of the string `^` (or beginning of line, using the /m modifier at the end)
2. allow `(` but don't catch it `(?:[\(])`
3. find a number `(\d*\.?\d+)` (int or float [with the dot])
4. have the `x` char, with (or without) space before and after `\s*x\s* - support multiple spaces here
5. have any of the supported units:
   5.1 cm, cms, in, inch, inches, mm, mms - followed by word boundry
   `(?:cms?|in|inch|inches|mms?)\b`
   **OR**
   5.2 Have the `"` char `|(?:[\"])`

Comment: You are welcome :) a voteup will be nice (if you haven't yet ;) )